# How to check if RegEx returns nil?

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I'm using this RegEx for detecting:

```
let text = myText.substringWithRange(myText[0].rangeOfString("(?<=\")[^\"]+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)!)
```

So it works perfectly, but when it cannot find what it searches it crashes! How can I pretend it?

I've tried to

```
if let text = ... {
    ...
}
```

it returns `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'` in this case. How can I pretend a crash?

Comment: Why did you create a new account? Are you interested in the first match only, or all matches in the string? I think you should ask that in the [original thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588098/how-to-check-if-regex-returns-nil).

Comment: @stribizhev there is no question about which part of using. I just want to prevent my crash when it cannot find anything

Comment: @NSNoob it shows me warning and delete `?` sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to unwrappe `Range<Index>` with `rangeOfString("(?<=\")[^\"]+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)!` and you need to test it to `nil`. Try do like this:

```
if let range = myText.rangeOfString("(?<=\")[^\"]+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
    let text = myText.substringWithRange(range)
    ...
}
```